# String intern in equals method

Tags: java

Is it a good practise to use String#intern() in equals method of the class. Suppose we have a class:

```
    public class A {
       private String field;
       private int number;
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if (obj == null) {
               return false;
           }
           if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
               return false;
           }
           final A other = (A) obj;   
           if ((this.field == null) ? (other.field != null) : !this.field.equals(other.field)) {
               return false;
           }
           if (this.number != other.number) {
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       }
   }
```

Will it be faster to use `field.intern() != other.field.intern()` instead of `!this.field.equals(other.field)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! Using `String.intern()` implicitly like this [is *not* a good idea](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html):

- It will *not* be faster. As a matter of fact it will be slower due to the use of a hash table in the background. A `get()` operation in a hash table contains a final equality check, which is what you want to avoid in the first place. Used like this, `intern()` will be called each and every time you call `equals()` for your class.
- `String.intern()` has a lot of memory/GC implications that you should not implicitly force on users of this class.

If you want to avoid full blown equality checks when possible, consider the following avenues:

- If you *know* that the set of strings is limited and you have repeated equality checks, you can use `intern()` for the field at object creation, so that any subsequent equality checks will come down to an identity comparison.
- Use an explicit `HashMap` or `WeakHashMap` instead of `intern()` to avoid storing strings in the GC permanent generation - this was an issue in older JVMs, not sure if it is still a valid concern.

Keep in mind that if the set of strings is unbounded, you *will* have memory issues.

That said, all this sounds like premature optimization to me. `String.equals()` is pretty fast in the general case, since it compares the string lengths before comparing the strings themselves. Have you profiled your code?

Comment: In modern JVMs, the permgen space is garbage collected.

Answer (score 4):

Good practice : Nope.  You're doing something tricky, and that makes for brittle, less readable code.  Unless this `equals()` method needs to be crazy performant (and your performance tests validate that it is in fact faster), it's not worth it.

Faster : Could be.  But don't forget that you can have unintended side effects from using the `intern()` method: http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/213/6-things-to-remember-about-saving-memory-with-the-string-intern-method/

Answer (score 3):

Any benefit gained by performing an identity comparison on the interned `String`s is likely to be outweighed by the associated cost of interning the `String`s.

In the above case you could consider interning the `String` when you instantiate the class, providing  the field is constant (in which case you should also mark it as `final`).  You could also check for `null` on instantiation to avoid having to check on each call to `equals` (assuming you disallow `null` `String`s).

However, in general these types of micro-optimisation offer little gain in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through this one step at a time...

The idea here is that if you use `String#intern`, you'll be given a canonical representation of that `String`. A pool of Strings is kept internally and each entry is guaranteed to be unique for that pool with regard to `equals`. If you call `intern()` on a String, then either a previously pooled identical String is going to be returned, or the String you called intern on is going to be pooled and returned.

So if we have two Strings `s1` and `s2` and we assume neither is null, then the following two lines of code are considered idempotent:

```
s1.equals(s2);
s1.intern() == s2.intern();
```

Let's investigate two assumptions we've made now:

1. `s1.intern()` and `s2.intern()` really will return the same object if `s1.equals(s2)` evaluates to `true`.
2. Using the `==` operator on two interned references to the same String will be more efficient than using the `equals` method.

The first assumption is probably the most dangerous of all. The [JavaDoc for the intern method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) tells us that using this method will return a canonical representation for an internally kept pool of Strings. But it **doesn't tell us anything about that pool**. Once an entry has been added to the pool, can it ever be removed again? Will the pool keep growing indefinitely or will entries occassionally be culled to make it act as a limited-size cache? You'd have to check the actual specifications of the Java Language and Virtual Machine to get any certainty, if they offer it at all. Having to check specs for a limited optimization is usually a big warning sign. Checking the source code for Sun's JDK 7, I see that `intern` is specified as a native method. So not only is the implementation likely to be vendor-specific, it might vary across platforms as well for VMs from the same vendor. All bets are off regarding stuff that's not in the spec.

On to our second assumption. Let's consider for a moment what it would take to intern a String... First of all, we'll need to check if the String is already in the pool. We'll assume they've tried to get an O(1) complexity going there to keep this fast by using some hashing scheme. But that's assuming we've got a hash of the String. Since this is a native method, I'm not certain what would be used... Some hash of the native representation or simply what `hashCode()` returns. I know from the source code of Sun's JDK that a String instance caches its hash code. It'll only be calculated the first time the method is called, and after that the calculated value will be returned. So at the very least, a hash must be calculated at least once if we're to use that. Getting a reliable hash of a String will probably involve arithmetic on each and every character, which can be expensive for lenghty values. Even once we have the hash and thus a set of Strings that are candidates for being matches in the interned pool, we'd still have to verify if one of these really **is** an exact match which would involve... an equality check. Meaning going through each and every character of the Strings and seeing if they match if trivial cases like inequal length can't be applied first. Worse still, we might have to do this for more than one other String like we'd do with a regular `equals`, since multiple Strings in the pool might have the same hash or end up in the same hash bucket.

So, that stuff we need to do to find out if a String was already interned or not sounds suspiciously like what `equals` would need to do. Basically, we've gained nothing and might even have made our `equals` implementation more expensive. At least, if we're going to call `intern` each and every time. So maybe we should intern the String right away and simply always use that interned reference. Let's check how class A would look if that were the case. I'm assuming the String field is initialized on construction:

```
public class A {

    private final String field;

    public A(final String s) {

        field = s.intern();

    }

}
```

That's looking a little more sensible. Any Strings that are passed to the constructor and are equal will end up being the same reference. Now we can safely use `==` between the `field` field of A instances for equality checks, right?

Well, it'd be useless. Why? If you check the source for `equals` in class String, you'll find that any implementation made by someone with half a brain will first do a `==` check to catch the trivial case where the instance and the argument are the same reference first. That could save a potentially heavy char-by-char comparison. I know the JDK 7 source I'm using for reference does this. So you're still better off using `equals` because it does that reference check anyway.

The second reason this'd be a bad idea is that first point way up above... We simply don't know if the instances are going to be kept in the pool indefinitely. Check this scenario, which may or may not occur depending on JVM implementation:

```
String s1 = ... //Somehow gets passed a non-interned "test" value
A a1 = new A(s1);
//Lots of time passes... winter comes and goes and spring returns the land to a lush green...
String s2 = ... //Somehow gets passed a non-interned "test" value
A a2 = new A(s2);
a1.equals(a2); //Totally returns the wrong result
```

What happened? Well, if it turns out the interned String pool will sometimes be culled of certain entries, then that first construction of an `A` could have `s1` interned, only to see it being removed from the pool, to have it later replaced by that `s2` instance. Since `s1` and `s2` are conceivably different instances, the `==` check fails. Can this happen? I've got no idea. I certainly won't go check the specs and native code to find out. Will the programmer that's going through your code with a debugger to find out why the hell `"test"` is not considered the same as `"test"`?

It's no problem if we're using `equals`. It'll catch the same instance case early for optimal results, which will benefit us when we've interned our Strings, but we won't have to worry about cases where the instances still end up being different because then `equals` is gonna do the classic compare work. It just goes to show that it's best not to second-guess the actual runtime implementation or compiler, because these things were made by people who know the specs like the back of their hands and really worry about performance.

So String interning manually can be of benefit when you make sure that...

- you're not interning each and every time, but just intern a String once like when intializing a field and then keep using that interned instance;
- you still use `equals` to make sure implementation details won't ruin your day and your code doesn't actually rely on that interning, instead relying on the implementation of the method to catch the trivial cases.

After keeping this in mind, surely it's worth using `intern()`? Well, we still don't know how expensive `intern()` is. It's a native method so it might be really fast. But we're not sure unless we check the code for our target platform and JVM implementation. We've also had to make sure we understand exactly what interning does and what assumptions we've made about it. Are you sure the next person reading your code will have the same level of understanding? They might be bewildered about this weird method they've never seen before that dabbles in JVM internals and might spend an hour reading the same gibberish I'm typing right now, instead of getting work done.

That's the problem right there... Before, it was simple. You used `equals` and were done. Now, you've added another little thing that can nestle itself in your mind and cause you to wake up screaming one night because you've just realized that **oh my God you've forgot to take out one of the `==` uses and that piece of code is used in a routine controlling the killer bots' apprisal of citizen disobedience and you've heard its JVM isn't too solid!**

Donald Knuth was famously attributed the quote...

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Knuth was clever enough to add in that 97% detail. Sometimes, thoroughly micro-optimizing a small portion of code can make a big difference. Say, if that piece of code takes up 30% of the program's runtime execution. The problem with micro-optimizations is that they tend to work on assumptions. When you start using `intern()` and believe that from then on it'll be safe to make reference equality checks, you've made a hell of a lot of assumptions. And even if you go down to implementation level to check if they're right, are you sure they will be in the next JRE version?

I myself have used `intern()` manually. Did it in some piece of code where the same handful of Strings are gonna end up in hundreds if not thousands of object instances as fields. Those fields are gonna be used as keys in `HashMaps` and are frequently used while doing some validation over those instances. I figured interning was worth it for two purposes: reducing memory overhead by making all those equal Strings one single instance and speeding up the map lookups, since they're using `hashCode()` and `equals`. But I've made damn sure that you can take all those `intern()` calls out of the code and everything will still work fine. The interning is just some icing on the cake in this case, a little extra that may or may not make a bit of difference along the road. But it's not an essential part of my code's correctness.

Long post, eh? Why'd I go through the trouble of typing all of this up? To show you that if you make micro-optimizations, you'd better know damn well what you're doing and willing to document it so thoroughly that you might as well not have bothered.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to say given that you have not specified hardware. Timing test are difficult to get right and are not universal. Have you done a timing test yourself?

My feeling is that the intern pattern would not be faster as each string would need to be matched to a possible string in a dictionary of all interned strings.